# What would the following SQL Server statement be in Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql

I am learning the differences between SQL Server & Oracle I would like to know what the following statement from SQL Server would be in Oracle:

```
DECLARE @Temp INT

SET @Temp = 9000

PRINT 'It's Over' + @Temp;
```

Thank you.

Edit: Of course damn grammar, also would require an convert, thanks for the db fiddle tool will be using that a lot!

Comment: This is syntactically incorrect in SQL Server, so such a conversion doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server:

```
Declare @Temp INT;
SET @Temp = 9000;           -- adding semicolons is a good practice
PRINT 'It's Over' + @Temp;  -- this line won't work at all 

-- should be
PRINT 'It''s Over' + CAST(@Temp AS VARCHAR(10));
```

Oracle:

```
DECLARE
   Temp INT;
BEGIN
   Temp := 9000;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('It''s Over' || Temp);
END;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3b4f7c1839ce467caf2a3513ce8d2242)**

Related: [Guide to Migrating from Oracle to SQL Server 2014
and Azure SQL Database](https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/C/A/FCA37580-53F5-46DB-A981-E08018661F09/Migrating-Oracle-to-SQL-Server-2014-and-Azure-SQL-DB.pdf)